# How to select all the text in a page in QuteBrowser?

Tags: python, browser

I need to map  to select the document like in a normal browser. I tried using ggVG ( vim equivalent) but 'V' didn't work. Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lower-case `v` should work (unless you use the QtWebEngine backend). Otherwise, `Ctrl-A` in insert mode does.

However, Stackoverflow is for programming questions - this isn't about programming. ;-)